# IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible with Google AppEngine 1.6.1

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Maybe it's a bug, but I'm posting here anyway.

I get the following issue on my local AppEngine testing server:

```
WARNING  2012-01-10 06:08:40,336 rdbms_mysqldb.py:90] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-01-10 06:08:40,470 appengine_rpc.py:159] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2012-01-10 06:08:40,474 appcfg.py:561] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-01-10 06:08:40,990 appcfg.py:574] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING  2012-01-10 06:08:47,643 dev_appserver.py:3344] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-01-10 06:08:47,654 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:638] Running application dev~project_name on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-01-10 06:08:47,654 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:640] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
INFO     2012-01-10 06:09:14,989 dev_appserver_index.py:338] Created 2 and deleted 0 index(es); total 2
WARNING  2012-01-10 06:09:15,480 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile /Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg'
ERROR    2012-01-10 06:09:16,927 bottle.py:746] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ca/Dropbox/Perso/projects/project_name/Source/project_name/lib/bottle.py", line 735, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/Users/ca/Dropbox/Perso/projects/project_name/Source/project_name/lib/bottle.py", line 1451, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/Users/ca/Dropbox/Perso/projects/project_name/Source/project_name/tools.py", line 41, in render_to_response
    template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 719, in get_template
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 165, in get_source
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 224, in open_if_exists
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 578, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Users/ca/Dropbox/Perso/Projects/project_name/Source/project_name/templates/tools_list.html'

INFO     2012-01-10 06:09:16,962 dev_appserver.py:2832] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2012-01-10 06:09:16,974 dev_appserver_index.py:255] Updating /Users/ca/Dropbox/Perso/projects/project_name/Source/project_name/index.yaml
WARNING  2012-01-10 06:11:36,153 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile /Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg'
```

I may be wrong, but it seems that it's an issue I was not getting before. Since Google App Engine was released on December 13, 2011; I'm wondering if it could come from this version.

I'm using pythonbrew, virtualenv, Mac Os X 10.6.8

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of referencing my variable using a hardcoded path variable, I'm now using:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

And it's working. I'll let you know if the issue comes back (I saw some articles describing it as being randomly recurrent).

I also applied the patch in comment 29 on  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4339

Comment: Where do I add this PROJECT_DIR ?

Comment: I have a `settings.py` which I import in all the files where I need to access those global variables.

Answer (score 14):

I have another answer to his problem, which I experienced by myself. If you have for example a templates directory like this:

```
templates
|-- css
|-- img
|-- js
|-- html
```

And your app.yaml file like this:

```
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates
```

You are not able to render a template with jinja2 if you use this name:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('html/index.html')
```

I think that's because the static_dir option somehow blocks this directory for jinja2, at least I think so, maybe it helps someone!

Comment: Yes, I had this issue. GAE currently doesn't allow accessing files in the `static_dir` from within the application code.

Comment: That's just the default behaviour. But it can be overriden using the `application_readable: true` option, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16541092/4495081

Answer (score 6):

Simply remove the file `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` from your site packages.

**Find the location of your site packages**

Start python CLI:

```
python
```

List site packages:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

Answer (score 3):

might be late but maybe would help someone else.
so, when you add

> ```
> jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'))
> ```

don't add
      `- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates`
to your **app.yaml** file

Comment: Or also add `application_readable: true`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16541092/4495081

Answer (score 0):

I have been puzzled by similar issue - IOError when importing an egg file / package from site-packages. I am using Ubuntu 13.10, GAE 1.8.8, virtualenv and python 2.7.

In the end, I've worked out that I could not import anything that I installed using easy_install (which by defaults puts egg files into site_packages).

Once I uninstalled all these eggs, and reinstalled using **pip install** command, everything  started working normally.

Hoping this will save someone else some time, as I will never get my wasted hours back.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this error is caused by dev_appserver.py returning fail for the open call when the file name matches a skip_files pattern in app.yaml. Check app.yaml even when running dev_appserver.py locally.