# file not accessible and cannot import library on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Okay, I am giving up. I cannot fix error message when I run my web2py app on google app engine. I have next output:

```
WARNING  2013-01-17 01:59:14,379 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: 
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg'

WARNING  2013-01-17 01:59:14,380 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/utils-0.1-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 
13] file not accessible: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/utils-
0.1-py2.7.egg'

ERROR    2013-01-17 01:59:14,490 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1251] Third 
party package Crypto must be included in the "libraries:" clause of your 
app.yaml file in order to be imported.

WARNING  2013-01-17 01:59:14,727 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:557] Blocking 
access to skipped file "/home/michael/webdev/web2py/gluon/rocket.py"
```

I tired to add Crypto library to app.yaml but GAE does not support it.
Also, I cannot understand why "file is not accessible".
Any ideas what is going on?

EDIT
my app.yaml file is :

```
application: wormsapp
version: 1
api_version: 1

# use this line for Python 2.5
#
#runtime: python

# use these lines for Python 2.7
# upload app with: appcfg.py update web2py (where 'web2py' is web2py's root     directory)
#
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true    # true for WSGI & concurrent requests (Python 2.7 only)

default_expiration: "24h"   # for static files

handlers:

- url: /(?P<a>.+?)/static/(?P<b>.+)
  static_files: applications/\1/static/\2
  upload: applications/(.+?)/static/(.+)
  secure: optional


#- url: /favicon.ico
#  static_files: applications/welcome/static/favicon.ico
#  upload: applications/welcome/static/favicon.ico

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: applications/crowdrandk/static/favicon.ico
  upload: applications/crowdrank/static/favicon.ico

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: applications/welcome/static/robots.txt
  upload: applications/welcome/static/robots.txt

- url: .*
#  script: gaehandler.py         # CGI
  script: gaehandler.wsgiapp    # WSGI (Python 2.7 only)
  secure: optional

admin_console:
  pages:
  - name: Appstats
    url: /_ah/stats

skip_files: |
 ^(.*/)?(
 (app\.yaml)|
 (app\.yml)|
 (index\.yaml)|
 (index\.yml)|
 (#.*#)|
 (.*~)|
 (.*\.py[co])|
 (.*/RCS/.*)|
 (\..*)|
 (applications/(admin|examples)/.*)|
 ((admin|examples|welcome)\.(w2p|tar))|
 (applications/.*?/(cron|databases|errors|cache|sessions)/.*)|
 ((logs|scripts)/.*)|
 (anyserver\.py)|
 (web2py\.py)|
 ((cgi|fcgi|modpython|wsgi)handler\.py)|
 (epydoc\.(conf|css))|
 (httpserver\.log)|
 (logging\.example\.conf)|
 (route[rs]\.example\.py)|
 (setup_(app|exe)\.py)|
 (splashlogo\.gif)|
 (parameters_\d+\.py)|
 (options_std.py)|
 (gluon/tests/.*)|
 (gluon/(rocket|winservice)\.py)|
 (contrib/(gateways|markdown|memcache|pymysql)/.*)|
 (contrib/(populate|taskbar_widget)\.py)|
 (google_appengine/.*)|
 (.*\.(bak|orig))|
 )$

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- appstats: on
- admin_redirect: on
- deferred: on

libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "latest"
- name: setuptools
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: what does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: @MartinBlech I added it to the question.

Comment: You should add `crypto` to libraries.

Comment: Can you include the part where you tried to add Crypto to your `app.yaml`?

Comment: You should also show the folder structure of your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to libraries:

```
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

or

```
 - name: pycrypto
   version: latest
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do you know what is the reason of warnings?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799304/ioerror-errno-13-file-not-accessible-with-google-appengine-1-6-1) helps you.

Comment: If you show the folder structure of your app maybe I can help you more.

Comment: See also [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7301)